# saving a date on a server using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, date, timezone

This should be pretty simple but for the life of me I can't make it work. The client inputs a date and time to the server. Then I take that date and save it on the server according to his timezone (which I already have) then display it to the client according to his timezone. I'm using spring mvc with hibernate.

For the server code I am doing the following:

```
                GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            GregorianCalendar timeCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(user.getTimezone());
            calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
            calendar.setTime(entryDate);
            timeCalendar.setTime(entryTime);

            timeCalendar.setTimeZone(tz);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

I retrieve the Date object from the calendar and save it.

the in the jsp I do the following:

```
<span class=""><fmt:formatDate timeZone="${timezone}" pattern="HH:mm a" value="${entry.entryDate}" /></span>
```

I always get it one or 2 hours different than it should be. I know I am missing something here. I just can't wrap my head around it. I feel like I am over computing this.

Comment: Can you give some more details like from which time zone to which time zone are you trying? Also the variables entryData and entryTime, what are the values that you are passing. I believe today there is a change in the DayLightSaving time globally so i believe the results are correct and you are not having that in mind. Check this out.

Comment: The Timezone with java Calendar and Date is a little confusing. I am not sure how you get the entryDate and entryTime - is there conversion problem from client? also there is no need to use two Calendar variable here, you are making it quite complicated. Log down the values in your code, then it should be clearer.